# Is there a way to implement data in a webpieces tags that can then be used to stream?

Tags: webpieces

Want to be able to get information from tags and then be able to send it to another server port.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused.  tags are used in html.  Webpieces streaming is for apis.  Generally 1 is not used with the other.  streaming apis are used for things like ndjson and tags are used in html files for dynamic content.

I realize when learning it's sometimes hard to ask the right question so I hope this helps. (and +1 just for trying).